# Tracking transitions from odesk job application to the personal website

Tags: php, http-referer, odesk

Here's the deal: I do freelancing jobs at odesk.com and I want to track transitions from my profile or the job applications that I left to my personal website.

For clients the url of the job application page is https://www.odesk.com/applications/xxxxxxxxx, where xxxxxxxxx is the id your job application.

So I thought I would just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to retrieve the previous url and take the job application id from it.

But guys from oDesk first redirect you to a page like this: https://www.odesk.com/leaving-odesk?ref=yyyyyyyyyyy.
And only then users get redirected to my website.

My question is: is there any way to know from which page (which job application) the visitor of my website came?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP_REFERER` in this case only tracks back to one page from where you came.

So you can't really on it. For example, when a user clicks an ad on a site which is orginated from [OSIpage](http://www.osipage.com), quick access application, the http_referrer contains OSIpage as the source page.

But on the other hand, when a user click the ad on the second page, the http_referrer becomes the same site.

`HTTP_REFERER` is therefore unreliable indeed. It might not be there, it might be forgotten, you just can't trust it if it's for security reasons.

Just try with `cookies` which gives you better control from where your site originated.